# Copy two columns from one table to another, but only unique values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `table1`, which has

```
MBID   |    Artist
__________________

123321   The Beatles
123214   Led Zeppelin
123321   The Beatles
```

How can I copy all of the **distinct** `MBID's` along with their corresponding `Artist` name, into a new table, so that the new table only has distinct `MBID`'s

```
 MBID   |    Artist
__________________

123321   The Beatles
123214   Led Zeppelin
```

I've tried

```
 insert into table2 (MBID,artist) 
 select distinct(table1.MBID),table1.artist 
 FROM danktable
```

But this gives me weird combinations and not only distinct MBID's

When I make the `MBID` a primary index, I get an error with this query because i'm getting non-unique `MBID` values.

Could someone help me out?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that for each `MBID` there is only one different artist?

Comment: I double checked and you are correct, there were duplicate MBID but some had different artists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
 insert into table2 (MBID,artist) 
 select MBID,max(artist)
 from table1
 group by MBID
```

Comment: Thanks @Grisha! I believe this did it. Why did I need to do `max(artist)`?

Comment: Cause maybe you have different values of `artist` for same `mbid`. You have to define which one to select...